# ionic2 , cordova build --prod not working with angularfire2

Tags: ionic2, angularfire2

I have used angularfire2 in an Ionic2 app. ionic serve is working fine, but when i use `sudo ionic cordova build android --prod` it gives error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../angularfire2/auth'` .

```
My ionic info is

    cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.8.6 
    Node       : v7.10.0
    npm        : 4.2.0 
    OS         : OS X El Capitan
    Xcode      : Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

package.json has

```
"angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.2",
```

I tried `npm install promise-polyfill --save-exact` but no use.

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of your Android_home environment variable. These errors often have to do with environment errors

Comment: Except for angularfire2 + cordova build --prod, every other project build fine using cordova build --prod

Comment: Also this problem comes on rc.2, angularfire2

Comment: @raju Environment is still worth checking out if you haven't already. I've been running normal builds for months but then my builds stop working in when using Firebase. All because of an environment variable error.

Comment: What to check in android_home. It is set in path and echoing properly. Other than angularfire.rc.2, everything is building properly

Comment: Check that it is set to the folder in Appdata and not the installation folder. The folder should look like something (on windows) C:/users/YOURNAME/appdata/local/android/bin...

Comment: ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\raju\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk.  I think this is correct path

Comment: Moreover this problem of angularfire.rc2 is already acknowledged by many users on GitHub.